# how to return rows where value is 0 and a previous value in the past 7 days was > 0?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I have a measurement for ICMP responses which has percent_packetloss, packets_received, packets_sent.
I want to query for rows where percent_packetloss is 100, but only if the ip previously had less than 100% packet loss any time in the previous 7 days.

Something like this:

```
from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -5m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "percent_packet_loss" and r["_value"] == 100)
  |> keep(columns: ["_value", "ip"]

from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -7d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["ip"] == <ip from previous query>)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "percent_packet_loss" and r["_value"] < 100)
```

Return rows from first query if the second query does not return None.

Can this type of operation be done in flux, if so, how?

I believe this solves the request:

```
alerts = from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -5m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "percent_packet_loss" and r["_value"] == 100)

noalerts = from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -7d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "packets_received" and r["_value"] > 0)
  
join(
    tables: {alerts, noalerts},
    on: ["ip"],
    method: "inner"
)

  |> keep(columns:["_time_alerts", "_value_alerts", "_value_noalerts", "account_alerts", "customer_alerts", "model_alerts", "site_alerts", "ip", "vendor_alerts"])
  |> distinct(column: "ip")
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refined and confirmed the following query meets the need.
The first query returns all rows with 100% loss.  The second query returns rows where packets received were > 0 in the past 7 days.  The two queries were then joined on the ip and matching rows from the first query are rendered.

```
alerts = from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -5m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "percent_packet_loss" and r["_value"] == 100)

noalerts = from(bucket: "customerData")
  |> range(start: -7d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ping")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "packets_received" and r["_value"] > 0)
  |> distinct(column: "ip")
  
join(
    tables: {alerts, noalerts},
    on: ["ip"],
    method: "inner"
)

  |> keep(columns:["_time", "account_alerts", "_value_alerts", "customer_alerts", "model_alerts", "site_alerts", "ip", "vendor_alerts"])
  |> rename(columns: {"account_alerts": "account", "_value_alerts": "percent_packet_loss", "customer_alerts": "customer", "site_alerts": "site", "vendor_alerts": "vendor", "model_alerts": "model"})
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).